# Fastest way to signal one thread from another

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

I have code that looks very similar to below. The code works, but I am curious if there are faster (lower latency) to signal one thread from another.

```
// condition_variable::wait (with predicate)
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread, std::this_thread::yield
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

int cargo = 0;
bool shipment_available()
{
    return cargo!=0;
}

void consume ()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.wait(lck,shipment_available);
        // consume:
        std::cout << cargo << '\n';
        cargo=0;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::thread consumer_thread (consume);

    // produce 10 items when needed:
    int i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        while (shipment_available()) std::this_thread::yield();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cargo = i++;
        cv.notify_one();

        if(i > 100)
            break;
    }

    consumer_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe make `cargo` a `std::atomic<int>` with `memory_order_relaxed` stores/loads and spin in the consumer thread? You'd get rid of the mutex+CV wait, but its a bit hard to tell without you posting some metrics and what you would consider "faster".

Comment: Can you give an example with the code above modified cargo to use a std::atomic<int> with memory_order_relaxed ?

Comment: Try out [this live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13322a78d39e3a7b). If you want me to expand a bit more on it, let me know and I'll write up an answer

Comment: Also please note that your code has a race. The producer thread can read `cargo` without holding a mutex, in `while (shipment_available())`

Comment: If latency is the #1 issue, then just put all the code into one thread, and the latency will be zero.  If through put is what you are really after, then you really want to use a queuing system and line up several jobs, so that both consumer and producer are running simultaneously.

Comment: You've also got a deadlock situation. If the consumer manages to lock the mutex before the producer bumps up `cargo`, the `cv.wait` will block forever.

Comment: Is the assumption correct that the real code has a) more than one consumer thread, and b) `cargo > 1` ? Because otherwise,this example doesn't make any sense at all. As it is, this is lockstep operation which will run more efficiently without threads.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, very useful to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many errors within your example, so I'll try to answer some other questions first, that you should have asked before this one.

#### About your example

First of all - this example does not make sense - it's actually synchronous: the two threads do not run simultaneously - one of them always waits for another. If, in such situation - performance is your main goal - you should put this code in single thread.

If you desire to use all the CPU cores to improve performance - you need to use a completely different asynchronous approach. You must use a thread pool of worker threads and feed tasks to them in queue. That means, that you must change the *architecture* of you code, and so - it goes out of scope of your question.

Then, your worker thread will not be ended by simple call to `thread::join` from another thread. `thread::join` blocks thread, that calls it, until target thread exits. So your application will hang at the point of `join` call, since your worker thread will never exit `while(1)` loop. You need to tell it somehow, that there will be no more work and it must finish. You may use special cargo value (negative for example) or stop flag, which I used in example below. Documentation for `std::thread`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

Also, if you guard some variables with mutex (and you **must** do it, if access to them is not atomic and they are used in several threads simultaneously), you should not use them without acquiring said mutex - it will always lead you to a some kind of synchronization error. I'm talking about `while (shipment_available())` in your main thread outside of `std::unique_lock` scope. With this - the code will compile fine and it will work fine, but someday, worker thread will write to `cargo` while the main thread is reading its value, and if accessing `int` is not atomic on your platform - something unexpected and totally unpredictable may happen. Maybe it will result in an app crash, maybe it will result in a wrong value being read. In this particular example - I can't imagine what could go wrong (but *Mark Lakata* in comments pointed out a situation), but in the general case - this is a terrible bug, which is incredible hard to catch. There is fine tutorial to C++11 threading and synchronization wich explains some of the pitfalls of this kind: http://baptiste-wicht.com/categories/c11-concurrency-tutorial.html

#### About your question:

To increase performance in your example, you could use a lock free approach with `std::atomic` objects. Documentation for `std::atomic`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

It should be said, that with this approach - threads do not sleep at all and will fully occupy two cores of you CPU. The `yield` makes it slightly better in a sense of a resource management, but will increase latency of the threads' communication, so it could be removed.

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

// make your cargo an atomic object
// it does not need a mutex to sync access to it from several threads
std::atomic<int> cargo = 0;

// you should have some method to stop thread, it wont stop by itself by calling std::thread::join()
// the most simple one - is atomic stop flag.
std::atomic<bool> consumerThreadStopFlag = false;

bool shipment_available()
{
   return cargo!=0;
}

void consume()
{
   while(!consumerThreadStopFlag) // while stop flag is not set
    {
      while(!shipment_available())
         std::this_thread::yield();

      std::cout << cargo << '\n';
      cargo=0;
    }
}

int main ()
{
   std::thread consumer_thread (consume);

   // produce 10 items when needed:
   int i=0;
   while(1)
   {
      while (shipment_available())
         std::this_thread::yield();

      cargo = i++;

   if(i > 100)
      break;
   }

   consumerThreadStopFlag = true; // setup stop flag
   consumer_thread.join();        // wait till thread leaves its while loop

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The link to the tutorial is broken meanwhile. Use https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/03/cpp11-concurrency-part1-start-threads.html instead.